# Why is systemd's default target is graphical on AWS stock image

Tags: debian, amazon-web-services, systemd

I noticed that on stock AWS Debian image (both Stretch and Jessie), the default target as reported by `systemctl get-default` is `graphical.target`.

AFAIK, systemd's `graphical.target` is equivalent to System-V runlevel 5. So my question is:

**Shouldn't that be `multi-user.target` by default (runlevel 3), and what is the risk/benefit of setting it to *multi-user* with:**

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Comment: And looks like nothing needs it, at least in a fresh installed Amazon Linux 2: `systemctl list-dependencies --before graphical.target` shows nothing running. I changed the default to `multi-user` and nothing apparent bad has happen.

Comment: If you `ls -la /etc/systemd/system/default.target` you'll see its the default target systemd is shipped with. I think for logistical reasons systemd just ships with the highest-level target by default.